# PHP: Generate HTML file from PHP

Tags: php

I'm currently trying to generate a HTML file from PHP files. So the plan is to loop thru the directory, read the content from the PHP file and generate a HTML file from it:

```
foreach ( glob( $template_root_path . '*.php' ) as $email ) {
    $email_content = readfile( $email );
}
```

How can I make now the .html file? I need to execute the PHP code so the HTML file only contains the result of the executed PHP file. Not sure how to handle this.

Comment: Either you make an HTTP request to the specific file in question (if available via HTTP), so that you will only get the rendered output as result, or you use output buffering and include the file directly in your script, so that you can catch the contents of the buffer afterwards.

Comment: @misorude Sounds like a plan but I'm not sure if this is a bad one. Isn't there a solution without a request? Maybe a transcriptor or something else?

Comment: `$myFile = "filename.html";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w'); // or die("error");  
$stringData = "your html code goes here";   
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);`

Comment: _“Isn't there a solution without a request? ”_ - that was the part after the “or” …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options.

#### 0. Change your architecture

Your code snippet looks extremely dangerous and seems to me like a bad architecture 
 – are you generating those PHP files? Why can you not have functions to build the `$email_content` directly? Can you use a templating engine?

However, if you have **no other option** and you are sure that the PHP files are safe (i.e. no user content):

#### 1. Output buffering

**Use this ONLY if your e-mails contain no sensitive data**, because bad programming in the included PHP files could cause information intended for one customer to leak to an e-mail for another customer (assuming you are sending e-mails to multiple customers).

```
<?php
foreach (glob($template_root_path . '*.php') as $email) {
  ob_start();
  include $email;
  $email_content = ob_get_clean();
}
```

More info: [Output Control Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php)

#### 2. Call `php`

Another option which isolates your calling script a bit more from the included PHP file is to run the `php` command. Note that you will not have access to HTTP-specific globals and functions.

```
<?php
foreach (glob($template_root_path . '*.php') as $email) {
  $email_content = shell_exec('php ' . $email);
}
```

More info: [Program Execution Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php)

Comment: This made it. Thank you :)